# Progress bar with steps

Tags: html, css

I am relatively new to programming (starting learning web dev less than 3 months ago), however already attempting to create a pretty complex (at least to me) progress bar.

I need this progress bar to not only change colors while the bar automatically moves from left to right as soon as the page loads - I've seen explanations all over the internet on how to do those.

However, once it is done, I need the colors for each portion (say, each 10%) to remain the same. So for example if the first 10% are a light red, the next 10% a darker red, etc... it first automatically goes through them as it animates, but then remains static with the different colors still seen and not just one last solid color.

The only way that I have found to do this so far is to create many different bars, each having a different z-index, however I am well aware this is very convoluted and probably not the most efficient way to implement this.

Like I said I am new to this so please be gentle :) I will show my code beneath. If anyone has a better suggestion, how I can have the different color separations within the same bar I would love to learn something new!

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div class="meter">
<span id="rd1" style="width: 5%"><p></p></span>
<span id="rd2" style="width: 10%"><p></p></span>
<span id="rd3" style="width: 15%"><p></p></span>
<span id="rd4" style="width: 20%"><p></p></span>
<span id="rd5" style="width: 25%"><p></p></span>
<span id="rd6" style="width: 30%"><p></p></span>
<span id="rd7" style="width: 35%"><p></p></span>
<span id="rd8" style="width: 40%"><p></p></span>
<span id="rd9" style="width: 45%"><p></p></span>
<span id="rd10" style="width: 50%"><p></p></span>
<span id="rd11" style="width: 55%"><p></p></span>
<span id="rd12" style="width: 60%"><p></p></span>
<span id="rd13" style="width: 65%"><p></p></span>
<span id="rd14" style="width: 70%"><p></p></span>
<span id="rd15" style="width: 75%"><p></p></span>
<span id="rd16" style="width: 80%"><p></p></span>
<span id="rd17" style="width: 85%"><p></p></span>
<span id="rd18" style="width: 90%"><p></p></span>
<span id="rd19" style="width: 95%"><p></p></span>
<span id="rd20" style="width: 100%"><p></p></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
`@keyframes color{
0% {
background-color: hsl(315, 100%, 75%);
width: 5%;
}
5% {
background-color: hsl(315, 100%, 70%);
width: 10%;
}
10% {
background-color: hsl(315, 100%, 65%);
width:15%;
}
15% {
background-color: hsl(315, 100%, 60%);
width: 20%;
}
20% {
background-color: hsl(315, 100%, 55%);
width: 25%;
}
25% {
background-color: hsl(315, 100%, 50%);
width: 30%;
}
30% {
background-color: hsl(320, 100%, 50%);
width:35%;
}
35% {
background-color: hsl(325, 100%, 50%);
width: 40%;
}
40% {
background-color: hsl(330, 100%, 50%);
width: 45%;
}
45% {
background-color: hsl(335, 100%, 50%);
width: 50%;
}
50% {
background-color: hsl(340, 100%, 50%);
width:55%;
}
55% {
background-color: hsl(345, 100%, 50%);
width: 60%;
}
60% {
background-color: hsl(350, 100%, 50%);
width: 65%;
}
65% {
background-color: hsl(355, 100%, 50%);
width: 70%;
}
70% {
background-color: hsl(360, 100%, 50%);
width:75%;
}
75% {
background-color: hsl(360, 95%, 50%);
width: 80%;
}
80% {
background-color: hsl(360, 90%, 50%);
width: 85%;
}
85% {
background-color: hsl(360, 85%, 50%);
width: 90%;
}
90% {
background-color: hsl(360, 80%, 50%);
width:95%;
}
95% {
background-color: hsl(360, 75%, 50%);
width: 100%;
}
}

.meter { 
height: 20px; 
position: relative;
top: 100px;
background: grey;
-moz-border-radius: 25px;
-webkit-border-radius: 25px;
border-radius: 25px;
padding: 10px;
box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px      rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
#rd1 {
display: block;
height: 140%;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color: hsl(315, 100%, 75%);
background-image: linear-gradient(
center bottom,
rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
rgb(84,240,84) 69%
);
box-shadow: 
inset 0 0px 0px  rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
inset 0 -6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
bottom: 4px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 20;
animation: color 4s linear 0s alternate;
}
#rd2 {
display: block;
height: 140%;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color: hsl(315, 100%, 70%);
background-image: linear-gradient(
center bottom,
rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
rgb(84,240,84) 69%
);
box-shadow: 
inset 0 0px 0px  rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
inset 0 -6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
bottom: 32px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 19;
animation: color 4s linear 0s alternate;
}
#rd3 {
display: block;
height: 140%;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color: hsl(315, 100%, 65%);
background-image: linear-gradient(
center bottom,
rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
rgb(84,240,84) 69%
);
box-shadow: 
inset 0 0px 0px  rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
inset 0 -6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
bottom: 60px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 18;
animation: color 4s linear 0s alternate;
}
#rd4 {
display: block;
height: 140%;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color: hsl(315, 100%, 60%);
background-image: linear-gradient(
center bottom,
rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
rgb(84,240,84) 69%
);
box-shadow: 
inset 0 0px 0px  rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
inset 0 -6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
bottom: 88px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 17;
animation: color 4s linear 0s alternate;
}
#rd5 {
display: block;
height: 140%;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color: hsl(315, 100%, 55%);
background-image: linear-gradient(
center bottom,
rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
rgb(84,240,84) 69%
);
box-shadow: 
inset 0 0px 0px  rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
inset 0 -6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
bottom: 116px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 16;
animation: color 4s linear 0s alternate;
}
#rd6 {
display: block;
height: 140%;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color: hsl(315, 100%, 50%);
background-image: linear-gradient(
center bottom,
rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
rgb(84,240,84) 69%
);
box-shadow: 
inset 0 0px 0px  rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
inset 0 -6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
bottom: 144px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 15;
animation: color 4s linear 0s alternate;
}
#rd7 {
display: block;
height: 140%;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color: hsl(320, 100%, 50%);
background-image: linear-gradient(
center bottom,
rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
rgb(84,240,84) 69%
);
box-shadow: 
inset 0 0px 0px  rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
inset 0 -6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
bottom: 172px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 14;
animation: color 4s linear 0s alternate;
}
#rd8 {
display: block;
height: 140%;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color: hsl(325, 100%, 50%);
background-image: linear-gradient(
center bottom,
rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
rgb(84,240,84) 69%
);
box-shadow: 
inset 0 0px 0px  rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
inset 0 -6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
bottom: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 13;
animation: color 4s linear 0s alternate;
}
#rd9 {
display: block;
height: 140%;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color: hsl(330, 100%, 50%);
background-image: linear-gradient(
center bottom,
rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
rgb(84,240,84) 69%
);
box-shadow: 
inset 0 0px 0px  rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
inset 0 -6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
bottom: 228px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 12;
animation: color 4s linear 0s alternate;
}
#rd10 {
display: block;
height: 140%;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color: hsl(335, 100%, 50%);
background-image: linear-gradient(
center bottom,
rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
rgb(84,240,84) 69%
);
box-shadow: 
inset 0 0px 0px  rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
inset 0 -6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
bottom: 256px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 11;
animation: color 4s linear 0s alternate;
}

#rd11 {
display: block;
height: 140%;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color: hsl(340, 100%, 50%);
background-image: linear-gradient(
center bottom,
rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
rgb(84,240,84) 69%
);
box-shadow: 
inset 0 0px 0px  rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
inset 0 -6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
bottom: 284px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 10;
animation: color 4s linear 0s alternate;
}

#rd12 {
display: block;
height: 140%;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color: hsl(345, 100%, 50%);
background-image: linear-gradient(
center bottom,
rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
rgb(84,240,84) 69%
);
box-shadow: 
inset 0 0px 0px  rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
inset 0 -6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
bottom: 312px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 9;
animation: color 4s linear 0s alternate;
}
#rd13 {
display: block;
height: 140%;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color:  hsl(350, 100%, 50%);
background-image: linear-gradient(
center bottom,
rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
rgb(84,240,84) 69%
);
box-shadow: 
inset 0 0px 0px  rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
inset 0 -6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
bottom: 340px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 8;
animation: color 4s linear 0s alternate;
}
#rd14 {
display: block;
height: 140%;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color:  hsl(355, 100%, 50%);
background-image: linear-gradient(
center bottom,
rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
rgb(84,240,84) 69%
);
box-shadow: 
inset 0 0px 0px  rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
inset 0 -6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
bottom: 368px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 7;
animation: color 4s linear 0s alternate;
}
#rd15 {
display: block;
height: 140%;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color:  hsl(360, 100%, 50%);
background-image: linear-gradient(
center bottom,
rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
rgb(84,240,84) 69%
);
box-shadow: 
inset 0 0px 0px  rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
inset 0 -6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
bottom: 396px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 6;
animation: color 4s linear 0s alternate;
}
#rd16 {
display: block;
height: 140%;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color:  hsl(360, 95%, 50%);
background-image: linear-gradient(
center bottom,
rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
rgb(84,240,84) 69%
);
box-shadow: 
inset 0 0px 0px  rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
inset 0 -6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
bottom: 424px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 5;
animation: color 4s linear 0s alternate;
}
#rd17 {
display: block;
height: 140%;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color:  hsl(360, 90%, 50%);
background-image: linear-gradient(
center bottom,
rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
rgb(84,240,84) 69%
);
box-shadow: 
inset 0 0px 0px  rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
inset 0 -6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
bottom: 452px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 4;
animation: color 4s linear 0s alternate;
}
#rd18 {
display: block;
height: 140%;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color:  hsl(360, 85%, 50%);
background-image: linear-gradient(
center bottom,
rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
rgb(84,240,84) 69%
);
box-shadow: 
inset 0 0px 0px  rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
inset 0 -6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
bottom: 480px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 3;
animation: color 4s linear 0s alternate;
}
#rd19 {
display: block;
height: 140%;
border-top-right-radius: 8px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color:  hsl(360, 80%, 50%);
background-image: linear-gradient(
center bottom,
rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
rgb(84,240,84) 69%
);
box-shadow: 
inset 0 0px 0px  rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
inset 0 -6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
bottom: 508px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 2;
animation: color 4s linear 0s alternate;
}
#rd20 {
display: block;
height: 140%;
border-top-right-radius: 8px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
background-color: hsl(360, 75%, 50%);
background-image: linear-gradient(
center bottom,
rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
rgb(84,240,84) 69%
);
box-shadow: 
inset 0 0px 0px  rgba(255,255,255,0.1),
inset 0 -6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
position: relative;
bottom: 536px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 1;
animation: color 4s linear 0s alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {background-position: 0px 0px, 0 0, 0 0}
    100% {background-position: -100px 0px, 0 0, 0 0}
}
```

Comment: Are you using JS to track the progress of something and control the bar, or are you trying to do a CSS-only bar purely for show? In any case,  I would structure your bar HTML with two overlapping div's (use z-index and position:absolute on one of them). The layer in behind would be your solid progress bar that spans the entire width and grows smoothly. The layer on top is your divisions (e.g. 10% each) where you can style each individually. Assuming you're using JS to control the progress bar, add some extra code to style the bar divisions as your progress counter passes certain thresholds.

Comment: Did you think about simply using a gradient instead of several colors ?

Comment: You could use the `bootstrap` library for making progress bars https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/progress/

Comment: So I'm not advanced enough in JS at this point, I'm trying to just accomplish this with CSS and HTML. I am using an animated gradient right now(90 degrees, kind of a wavy look), didn't post that because the code's long as it is. How would you propose having that gradient and a gradient that would give me the look I'm looking for at the same time, would that be possible?

Comment: Hey guys, so the gradient idea worked well! I got that part done. My only other question is - and this might be a no brainer to some of you, but how do I have it so each bar(say I want several on the same page) animates to its own width(%)...right now the animation I posted above moves all my bars the same(to 100%).

Comment: @OriZ I think you can post your solution as an answer here and ask a separate question for your other problem. =)